# Circle, Ellipse, closed-curve-with-n-foci?

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, curves

So a closed curve is called a circle if all its points are at the same distance from a center point.

Similarly, if for each point in a closed curve the distances to two foci always add up to the same amount, it is called an ellipse.

What is a closed curve called if for each point, the sum of the distances to three or more points is constant?

---

In equations

$\sqrt{(x-x_{c})^{2}+(y-y_{c})^{2}}=r\\$
Circle

$\sqrt{(x-x_{1})^{2}+(y-y_{1})^{2}}+\sqrt{(x-x_{2})^{2}+(y-y_{2})^{2}}=d\\$
Ellipse

$\sqrt{(x-x_{1})^{2}+(y-y_{1})^{2}}+\sqrt{(x-x_{2})^{2}+(y-y_{2})^{2}}+\sqrt{(x-x_{3})^{2}+(y-y_{3})^{2}}=d\\$
???

$\vdots$

---

<s>Also, both the circle and the ellipse can be restated in a $y=$ form (like $y=y_{c}\pm\sqrt{r^{2}-(x-x_{c})^{2}}$ for the circle). That is, splitting the respective curve into two functions of the form $y=f(x)$, since for any given x-coordinate, there are at most two points that satisfy the circle/ellipse's equation. As far as I can tell, the kind of closed curve described by these kinds of equations never change from curving clockwise to anti-clockwise, so there also should be at most two points per x-coordinate that satisfy the equation, so it it seems to me that there must be two y=f(x) functions for each such curve as well, but it seems to be beyond my abilities to extract them from their equations.</s> (I managed to get rid of the roots and isolate all the y terms, but the result is an equation of degree 8, and only special cases of equations above degree 4 are solveable.)

Comment: [n-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse), also known as multifocal ellipse, polyellipse, egglipse, k-ellipse and Tschirnhaus'sche Eikurve .

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a term for the curves generated by subtracting some focal distances from the general sum rather than adding them? Say $sqrt((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)+sqrt((x-c)^2+(y-d)^2)-sqrt((x-e)^2+(y-f)^2)$ (looks like an ellipse with a dent).

Comment: As an illustration, this link shows the respective curves of $sqrt((x-1)²+(y+1)²)+sqrt((x-1)²+(y-2)²)+sqrt((x+2)²+y²)=d$, $sqrt((x-1)²+(y+1)²)+sqrt((x-1)²+(y-2)²)=d$ and $sqrt((x-1)²+(y+1)²)+sqrt((x-1)²+(y-2)²)-sqrt((x+2)²+y²)=d$: https://imgur.com/a/9GvwT (all with a value for $d$ to make them go through the same point; in this case $d={7.311102550928, 0.1, 3.705551275464})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a closed curve called if for each point, the sum of the distances to three or more points is constant?

Essentially achille hui answered your question in their comment. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) there are several names, including $n$-ellipse, [multifocal ellipse](http://renyi.mta.hu/~p_erdos/1982-18.pdf), [polyellipse](http://www.ams.org/journals/qam/1977-35-02/S0033-569X-1977-0448883-X/S0033-569X-1977-0448883-X.pdf), [egglipse](https://doi.org/10.1080/0020739870180104), [$k$-ellipse](http://math.ucsd.edu/~njw/PUBLICPAPERS/kellipse_imaproc_toappear.pdf), and [Tschirnhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfried_Walther_von_Tschirnhaus)'sche Eikurve.

> I managed to get rid of the roots and isolate all the y terms, but the result is an equation of degree 8, and only special cases of equations above degree 4 are solveable.

Wikipedia further writes that

> If $n$ is odd, the algebraic degree of the curve is $2^n$, while if $n$ is even the degree is $2^n - \binom{n}{n/2}$.<sup>[[5]](http://math.ucsd.edu/~njw/PUBLICPAPERS/kellipse_imaproc_toappear.pdf):(Thm. 1.1)</sup>

So a degree 8 for the case of 3 foci is consistent with this. Solvability isn't discussed in the Wikipedia atricle, but I'd be surprised if it were solvable for generic positions of the foci.